# Flask-Dance OAuth with Custom OAuth provider

Tags: python-2.7, flask, oauth, authorization, flask-sqlalchemy

I m trying to use Flask-Dance OAuth with custom OAuth provider.I have integrated it successfully with mentioned service providers like github. 
But when I try to use authorise:github with OAuth using Custom Provider it does not get authorise, account_info.ok prints as false.
What I want to do is using Custom Provider I would be able to authorise any available OAuth Provider.
I can't figure out how to use Custom Provider mentioned at http://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#custom
Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_dance.consumer import OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

#export OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT=1

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='thisissupposedtobesecretkey'

client_id = "*********************",
client_secret = "********************",

example_blueprint = OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint("github", __name__,
                                    client_id=client_id,
                                    client_secret=client_secret,
                                    scope=None,
                                    base_url="https://api.github.com/",
                                    authorization_url="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize",
                                    token_url="https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token",
                                    redirect_url=None,
                                    redirect_to=None,
                                    login_url=None,
                                    authorized_url=None,
                                    session_class=None,
                                    backend=None,
                                    )

app.register_blueprint(example_blueprint, url_prefix="/login")

@app.route('/example')
def login():
    if not example_blueprint.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for('example_blueprint.login'))
    try:
        account_info=example_blueprint.session.get("/user")
        print "i m here ....."
        print account_info.ok
        return account_info
    except Exception as e:
        print "i m here .....",e

    #

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the authorized method from the OAuth2Session instance which automatically loads tokens for the OAuth provider from the storage. So you need to change the following lines of code:

```
@app.route('/example')
def login():
    if not example_blueprint.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for('example_blueprint.login'))
```

to

```
@app.route('/example')
    def login():
        if not example_blueprint.session.authorized:
            return redirect(url_for('example_blueprint.login'))
```

Cheers